# "Cannot find -lgdbm" when making xemacs in FreeBSD10

Tags: compiling, freebsd, make, libraries, xemacs

I have been trying to install xemacs 21.4.22 in FreeBSD10 x64. Once I run `./configure` and try to run `make` it gives me this error with `libgdm.so`  library

```
[eddyraz@laptop-eddyraz] ~/proyectos/xemacs/xemacs-21.4.22% sudo make
Password:
cd ./lib-src && make   CC='cc' CFLAGS='-g -O3 -Wall -Wno-switch -Winline -Wmissing-prototypes -Wsign-compare -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith' LDFLAGS='' CPPFLAGS='' all
cc -g -O3 -Wall -Wno-switch -Winline -Wmissing-prototypes -Wsign-compare -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -I. -I../src -I/usr/home/eddyraz/proyectos/xemacs/xemacs-21.4.22/lib-src -I/usr/home/eddyraz/proyectos/xemacs/xemacs-21.4.22/src  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H /usr/home/eddyraz/proyectos/xemacs/xemacs-21.4.22/lib-src/ellcc.c  -Xlinker -z -Xlinker nocombreloc -Xlinker -R/usr/local/lib -lgdbm -lncurses -lpq -lldap -llber -lm -lutil -lgcc -lc -lgcc /usr/lib/crtend.o /usr/lib/crtn.o -o ellcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdbm
cc: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/home/eddyraz/proyectos/xemacs/xemacs-21.4.22/lib-src
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/home/eddyraz/proyectos/xemacs/xemacs-21.4.22
```

I have checked in `/usr/local/lib` and found `libgdm`.

```
[eddyraz@laptop-eddyraz] ~/proyectos/xemacs/xemacs-21.4.22% cd /usr/local/lib
[eddyraz@laptop-eddyraz] /usr/local/lib% ls -l | grep libgdm
[eddyraz@laptop-eddyraz] /usr/local/lib% ls -l | grep libgdbm
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     86310 17 jun 16:57 libgdbm.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel       971 17 jun 16:57 libgdbm.la
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel        12 17 jun 16:57 libgdbm.so -> libgdbm.so.4
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     42032 17 jun 16:57 libgdbm.so.4
[eddyraz@laptop-eddyraz] /usr/local/lib%
```

Why does `make` error with `cannot find -lgdbm`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

then run make again. A note that you don't need `sudo` to run `make`.

From [FreeBSD ldconfig documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ldconfig&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html):

> The LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable can be used to override the
>   use
>        of   directories (or the order thereof) from the cache or to specify additional directories  where shared libraries might
>   be    found.
>        LD_LIBRARY_PATH is   a `:' separated list of directory paths which are
>        searched by the dynamic linker when it needs to load a shared library.
>        It   can be viewed as the run-time equivalent of the -L switch of ld(1).

Comment: Done that, but still got the same error.